# GetValue() in ECMAScript5.1

Tags: javascript

I was checking [this article](http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/), where it says in this line `(1,eval)(‘1+1’)`

> "comma operator (in (1, eval) example) perform GetValue on its
>   operands. As a result, (1, eval) evaluate to a value, whereas eval and
>   (eval) — to a Reference."

what does he mean by `(1, eval) evaluate to a value`? What is this value about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `eval` does exactly depends on how it is called, whether it is a [Direct call to `eval`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.1.1) or not:

> A direct call to the eval function is one that is expressed as a
>   *CallExpression* that meets the following two conditions:
>
> The [Reference](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7) that is the result of
>   evaluating the *MemberExpression* in the *CallExpression* has an
>   [environment record](http://es5.github.io/#x10.2) as its base value
>   and its reference name is "`eval`".
>
> The result of calling the abstract operation
>   [GetValue](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1) with that
>   [Reference](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7) as the argument is the
>   standard built-in function defined in
>   [15.1.2.1](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.1).

So if you evaluate `eval`, it is a reference to the eval function (satisfying the conditions described above), whereas when you evaluate `(1, eval)` you will get the eval function itself. Calling the one or the other makes a difference for `eval`. Let's compare the syntax trees:

```
                    (eval)()
                 CallExpression
                    /      \
                   /        \
             (eval)         ()
        MemberExpression   Arguments
       PrimaryExpression
       Grouping Operator
               |
               |
              eval
           Expression
       PrimaryExpression
           Identifier
```

This is evaluated top-down. To call, the *MemberExpression* is evaluated, for which the *Grouping Operator* is evaluated, which just returns the result of the underlying [*Identfier*](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.2) which is that **Reference** [resolving the name "eval" in the current scope](http://es5.github.io/#x10.3.1). Then, [the call does](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.3) apply [GetValue](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1) on that reference, which returns [the eval function](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.1); which then is *called*. Since the above qualifies as a **direct call**, the [code is executed differently](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.2).

```
                     (1,eval)()
                   CallExpression
                      /      \
                     /        \
               (1,eval)        ()
         MemberExpression     Arguments
        PrimaryExpression
        Grouping Operator
                 |
                 |
              1,eval
           Expression
         Comma Operator
           /         \
          /           \
         1             eval
    Expression    AssignmentExpression
        ...              ...
PrimaryExpression   PrimaryExpression
      Literal         Identifier
```

Again, this is evaluated top-down. The same things as above happen, but also an additional step: The [comma operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.14). The point now is that it does call GetValue on the evaluation result of the `eval` Identifier, so it does return the eval function itself instead of just the reference that will resolve to it. The CallExpression will then use that **value** (the function) it got, and though it calls the same function as above this does not qualify the conditions, making only an **indirect call**.

Comment: my confusion is why `(eval)` is evaluated to a reference whereas `(1, eval)` is to a value? what is this `value` all about?

Comment: The value is the `eval` function that is to be called.

Comment: what are the differences between eval as a reference and eval as a value?

Comment: [The evaled code cares about that](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.2). This is basically the point of the article you were reading.

Comment: @Bergi +1 I was just too lazy to draw the graph and post that as an answer :-)